# UI Bug when viewing my suggested edit

Tags: bug

Because I'm mildly compulsive, I was looking at the review status of my recent edit. I expanded the information about the reviewers by clicking the `(more)` link and then clicked `(less)` to un-expand (shrink? contract?) it. When I did that, I found that the suggested edit information did not move back up to match the new bottom of the approver section. As we cannot grow crops in this white space, it's probably a bug, albeit a small one.

[image: Screen shot of suggested edit review page showing gap in UI between reviewer section and suggested edit section]